# Direct show application, testing with multiple capture sources (formats)

Tags: testing, directshow, capture

How do you Direct Show developers, deal with the testing of multiple capture source formats?

I need to test various formats of input,  such as rgb24 (web cam),  DV,  MPEG4.

I can achieve this by connecting a variety of capture hardware to my development computer and examining the output and the filter graph, but this potentially requires me to have a lot of hardware,  there has to be a better way?

I have seen virtual webcams which provide a capture source filter but they give no control over the output format.

Is there a virtual capture device that would allow the testing of multiple capture formats without the purchase of multiple hardware or is there a dedicated hardware capture source that is generally used for testing as it provides configurable and multiple formats?

How do you test different capture formats without buying a myriad of capture devices?

Comment: Various simulations, test/development environments and, certainly, tests on real hardware. There is no other way to cover everything otherwise: too many formats, too much flexibility, third party components are too often introducing unexpected behavior and require fitting work.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I can find the flexibility a great asset, but also overwhelming. And I agree that hardware conformance is a big deal.  Perhaps I need to agree a white list of 'verified'  compatible hardware with the client to reduce this pool. And perhaps I need to develop a capture source filter that would allow me to simulate various formats for the application to find as a capture source?

Comment: With a "proper" approach you write code that either works out of the box with various hardware, and requires minimal troubleshooting/update for other models of interest. The problem here is that hardware often comes with drivers which do not implement integration cleanly. DirectShow based software, including popular, also does not always do things properly (including well known apps such as Skype, Adobe FMLE). Support for compressed capture video formats, in particular, almost always require model-specific attention: many vendors implement things in questionable ways.